# Parsing Image into ListView using JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

How to parse Images into ListView using JSON, I am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/), and able to fetch string into ListView, but now i also need to fetch images into ListView, to fetch images i am using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) tutorial

I am little bit concern what to use below to get Images into ListView,

```
           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, TAG_IMAGE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile, R.id.listImage });
```

I added all the required classes into my existing project

Comment: So what is the problem after using those links????

Comment: are you trying to have custom list item with image view inside ?

Comment: not able to show images into List

Comment: @VilenMelkumyan yes using JSON

Comment: Are you using ImageLoader class?

Comment: Use Custom ListView and then use ImageLoader class in that.

Comment: is it possible in existing code ?

Comment: Yes for that you have to use Custom Listview.

Comment: i am using custom listview but not getting images in that

Comment: If is it not possible to show code then show your JSON data

Comment: Well it doesn't matter whether your collection represented via JSON or something else, you need to create custom ArrayAdapter and pass your item view to it, then in in getView Method assign appropriate properties to your view items
Simple google search for custom ArrayAdapter will give you lot of examples.

Comment: Make sure that the hosting service you are using to host the images lets you actually download the images. Most of the free hosting services don't :)